# Html plublisher - Could not copy html report to other path within workspace

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, html-reports-jenkins

Trying to copy the HTML publisher report to another path in same workspace.

Added below script in jenkinsfile

```
  publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,includes: '**/*.png', keepAll: true, reportDir: target/cucumber-html-reports', reportFiles: report.html', reportName: 'HTMLReport', reportTitles: ''])
```

Jenkins Console log

```
    [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...

    [htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /apps/cloudbees-je/cloudbees-data/workspace/TEST/all_test/target/cucumber-html-reports to    /apps/jenkins/cloudbees-data/jobs/TEST/jobs/all_test/builds/42/htmlreports/HTMLReport
```

I am trying to copy the HTML publisher output “/apps/jenkins/cloudbees-data/jobs/TEST/jobs/all_test/builds/42/htmlreports/HTMLReport" To ${env.WORKSPACE}/report    by running below script in jenkinsfile

```
   sh "cp /apps/jenkins/cloudbees-data/jobs/TEST/jobs/all_test/builds/42/htmlreports/HTMLReport ${env.WORKSPACE}/report/"
```

ERROR :

```
   cp: cannot stat ‘/apps/jenkins/cloudbees-data/jobs/DSO_TEST/jobs/dso_automation_ete_test/builds/46/htmlreports/HTMLReport’: No such file or directory
```

Any Suggestion to copy the HTML publisher report to another path.Not understanding why o could not see an files in the HTMl publisher reported path.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if all files are available at the defined location.
You can then do a copy command using :

```
cp /apps/jenkins/cloudbees-data/jobs/DSO_TEST/jobs/dso_automation_ete_test/builds/46/htmlreports/* ${env.WORKSPACE}/report/
```

Comment: after running the cp cmd as above. Got this error.        CP: cannot stat ' /apps/jenkins/cloudbees-data/jobs/DSO_TEST/jobs/dso_automation_ete_test/builds/56/htmlreports/*': NO SUCH FILE or DIRECTORY

Comment: @Bustaq do you see the files in the directory manually?

Comment: I was running my test from Jenkins node A, I could find that  html publisher publishing reports to Jenkins master node.  I was expecting that html publisher would generate html file with inline CSS, so planning to take out the html file only. But in the published folder has the CSS,js as external stylesheet . My required is to attached inline html file.